# How to fix : [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

Tags: python, git, error-handling, directory

im trying to implement a github repo but whenever i tried to run it i get this error:

[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:'DATASET_PATH\1.jpg'

here is the repo link: https://github.com/ellisalicante/OpenFilter/tree/main/OpenFilter

here is the main.py

```
import random
import time
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse
from PIL import Image

import pyautogui as auto

positions = {
    "new_file": (1220,750),
    "many_cam": (1150,250),
    "many_cam_confirm": (1180,280),
    "screen": (42,305,510,510),
    "right_filter": (430,980),
    "left_filter": (150,980)
}

def drag_and_drop(start, end):
    auto.mouseDown(start)
    auto.moveTo(end)
    auto.mouseUp()

def sleep(ms):
    seconds = ms / 1000
    seconds += random.random()*seconds/10
    time.sleep(seconds)

def h_padding(img):
    background = Image.new('RGB', (img.size[0] + 5*img.size[0]//285, img.size[1]))
    background.paste(img, (background.size[0] - img.size[0], 0))
    return background

def v_padding(img):
    background = Image.new('RGB', (img.size[0], img.size[1] + 150*img.size[1]//285))
    background.paste(img, (0, (background.size[1] - img.size[1])//2))
    return background
    
def main(path, output, n_filters, move_right):
    filter = 0
    for img_folder in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
        print(img_folder)
        out_folder = os.path.join(output, img_folder)
        img_folder = os.path.join(path, img_folder)
        if not os.path.isdir(out_folder):
            os.makedirs(out_folder)
        if len(os.listdir(img_folder)) == len(os.listdir(out_folder)):
            filter += 1
            if filter == n_filters:
                filter = 0
            continue
        print("FILTER", filter)
        
        for iter, img_name in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(img_folder))):
            out_path = os.path.join(out_folder, img_name)
            img_path = os.path.join(img_folder, img_name)
            if os.path.isfile(out_path):
                continue
            img = Image.open(img_path)
            img_size = img.size
            img = v_padding(h_padding(img))
            img.save(os.path.join("swapper", img_name))
            sleep(2000)
            if iter == 0:
                sleep(2000)
            drag_and_drop(positions["new_file"], positions["many_cam"])
            sleep(800)
            auto.click(positions["many_cam_confirm"])
            sleep(2000)
            screenshot = auto.screenshot(region=positions["screen"]).resize(img_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            screenshot.save(out_path)            
            os.remove(os.path.join("swapper", img_name))
        
        filter += 1
        if filter == n_filters:
            filter = 0
            if n_filters == 1:
                continue
            for _ in range(n_filters - 2):
                auto.click(positions["right_filter"] if not move_right else positions["left_filter"])
                sleep(3000)
            auto.click(positions["right_filter"] if not move_right else positions["left_filter"])
            sleep(20000)
        else:
            auto.click(positions["left_filter"] if not move_right else positions["right_filter"])
            sleep(20000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Parses command.'
    )
    parser.add_argument('--dataset', dest='path', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--output', dest='output', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--n_filters', dest='n_filters', type=int, default=8)
    parser.add_argument('--move_right', dest='move_right', action='store_true')
    main(**vars(parser.parse_args()))
```

i tried to place a folder name called DATASET_PATH and place it to where i run the code.

error that i get

```
PS C:\Windows\system32\OpenFilter\OpenFilter> python .\main.py --dataset DATASET_PATH --output OUTPUT_PATH
1.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Windows\system32\OpenFilter\OpenFilter\main.py", line 97, in <module>
    main(**vars(parser.parse_args()))
  File "C:\Windows\system32\OpenFilter\OpenFilter\main.py", line 47, in main
    if len(os.listdir(img_folder)) == len(os.listdir(out_folder)):
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Dizin adı geçersiz: 'DATASET_PATH\\1.jpg'
PS C:\Windows\system32\OpenFilter\OpenFilter>
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: It seems you gave a **file** `DATASET_PATH\1.jpg` as directoy to `os.listdir`. You should check if `img_folder` is a file in the same way you did for `out_folder`.